# Scroll to div via data attribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a program that scrolls on div via data-id. I place my data-id on my menus and trying to scroll them on their respective id divs.

Here's my HTML look like:

```
<header>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a> <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-id="about" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-id="testimonials"  href="#">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item border-button">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


  <section id="big-hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-5 pl-5">
          <h1 class="display-4 main-text-white">Manage Your Contacts Online</h1>
          <p class="lead sub-text-white">We provide a seemless way to manage your contacts. Keeping them on file and accessible online.</p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg main-btn" type="button">Get Started</button>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/intro-img.svg"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
          <h1 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center">Organize Your Contacts At Ease</h1>
          <p class="lead sub-text-blue text-center">Your easy go online address book for with intuitive<br>
          contact management for individuals, teams & small businesses.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 offset-lg-1"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/list-img.svg"></div>
        <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-5">
          <p class="lead sub-text-blue left">If you’re doing all you can to organize all the people you are communicating with, you’re collecting contacts from different people categories, you might worry that some of your contacts are getting lost in the shuffle? Contact Hub makes it easy for you to:</p>
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x icon-radius float-left"></i>
            <p class="lead sub-text-blue float-right">Add, update, delete, and segment your contact list online.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-2x icon-radius float-left"></i>
            <p class="lead sub-text-blue float-right">Categorize your contacts accordingly so you can stay organize with your contact list.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="fa fa-book fa-2x icon-radius float-left"></i>
            <p class="lead sub-text-blue float-right">Clean, manage, and grow your list. This app helps you stay organized year round.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="testimonials">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <h1 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center">Testimonials</h1><img class="img-thumbnail img-rounded mx-auto d-block" src="img/testimonial.jpg">
        <p class="lead sub-text-blue text-center">"I love contact hub. It has been helpful to me so far in managing my contacts.<br>
        I don't worry of loosing my contacts on my phone since I can easily jump on the app and take a<br>
        look on my contacts per category. Definitely recommended."</p>
        <h4 class="testimonials-name">- CHRISTINE JACOBS, Contact Hub User</h4>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p class="text-center">© Copyright 2020. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </footer>
```

And here's how I selected data attribute so that they can scroll smoothly on each div:

```
<script>
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $( '#' + data_id).offset().top
  }, 'slow');
</script>
```

Somehow this did not work. I was wondering how can I fix this so that each data-id can scroll to each div?

Comment: Where does `data_id` come from? How is it defined?

Comment: I can't see any click events which can trigger the scroll.

Comment: How the variable `data_id` will get a value?

Comment: data_id must scroll to the equivalent section id ON CLICK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to element using data-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471679/scroll-to-element-using-data-attributes)

Comment: @MarcSolva check my answer and check this https://jsfiddle.net/h736c4va/

Answer (score 0):

`data_id` in your snippet is an undefined `var`, apart from that all looks good, and works as well.

```js
function scrollToData(data_id){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + data_id).offset().top
  }, 'slow');
}

scrollToData("about")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a> <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-id="about" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-id="testimonials" href="#">Testimonials</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item border-button">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>


<section id="big-hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-lg-5 pl-5">
        <h1 class="display-4 main-text-white">Manage Your Contacts Online</h1>
        <p class="lead sub-text-white">We provide a seemless way to manage your contacts. Keeping them on file and accessible online.</p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg main-btn" type="button">Get Started</button>
      </div>
      <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/intro-img.svg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
        <h1 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center">Organize Your Contacts At Ease</h1>
        <p class="lead sub-text-blue text-center">Your easy go online address book for with intuitive<br> contact management for individuals, teams & small businesses.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 offset-lg-1"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/list-img.svg"></div>
      <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-5">
        <p class="lead sub-text-blue left">If you’re doing all you can to organize all the people you are communicating with, you’re collecting contacts from different people categories, you might worry that some of your contacts are getting lost in the shuffle? Contact Hub makes it easy
          for you to:</p>
        <div class="icon-box">
          <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x icon-radius float-left"></i>
          <p class="lead sub-text-blue float-right">Add, update, delete, and segment your contact list online.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-box">
          <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-2x icon-radius float-left"></i>
          <p class="lead sub-text-blue float-right">Categorize your contacts accordingly so you can stay organize with your contact list.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-box">
          <i class="fa fa-book fa-2x icon-radius float-left"></i>
          <p class="lead sub-text-blue float-right">Clean, manage, and grow your list. This app helps you stay organized year round.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="testimonials">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <h1 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center">Testimonials</h1><img class="img-thumbnail img-rounded mx-auto d-block" src="img/testimonial.jpg">
        <p class="lead sub-text-blue text-center">"I love contact hub. It has been helpful to me so far in managing my contacts.<br> I don't worry of loosing my contacts on my phone since I can easily jump on the app and take a<br> look on my contacts per category. Definitely recommended."</p>
        <h4 class="testimonials-name">- CHRISTINE JACOBS, Contact Hub User</h4>

      </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <p class="text-center">© Copyright 2020. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: I tried clicking on testimonials and about link and they are not scrolling to their respective ids. data_id must scroll to its equivalent section id on CLICK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***scroll-behavior: smooth;*** css property to achieve this.

```
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

You can set this behavior to any scrolling container. By default it is the root of the document that is `<html>`.

> You need to use ids of the elements in the links such as `href="#id"`

```css
html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}

div {
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#last">go to last</a></li>
</ul>

<section>
  <div id="first">first</div>
  <div id="second">second</div>
  <div id="last">last</div>
</section>
```

---

But if you want things to work on click then you have to bind event to the relative element.

```
function goToElement(data_id){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $( '#' + data_id).offset().top
  }, 'slow');
}
```

Then you have to bind an event to the `nav-link` element.

```
$('.nav-link').on('click', function(){
     goToElement($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: I tried clicking on testimonials and about link and they are not scrolling to their respective ids. data_id must scroll to its equivalent section id on CLICK.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```js
  $(".nav-link").click(function(){
  
  var topData= $( '#' + $(this).attr("data-id")).offset();
 
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: topData.top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a> <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-id="about" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-id="testimonials"  href="#">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item border-button">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


  <section id="big-hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-5 pl-5">
          <h1 class="display-4 main-text-white">Manage Your Contacts Online</h1>
          <p class="lead sub-text-white">We provide a seemless way to manage your contacts. Keeping them on file and accessible online.</p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg main-btn" type="button">Get Started</button>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/intro-img.svg"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
          <h1 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center">Organize Your Contacts At Ease</h1>
          <p class="lead sub-text-blue text-center">Your easy go online address book for with intuitive<br>
          contact management for individuals, teams & small businesses.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 offset-lg-1"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/list-img.svg"></div>
        <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-5">
          <p class="lead sub-text-blue left">If you’re doing all you can to organize all the people you are communicating with, you’re collecting contacts from different people categories, you might worry that some of your contacts are getting lost in the shuffle? Contact Hub makes it easy for you to:</p>
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x icon-radius float-left"></i>
            <p class="lead sub-text-blue float-right">Add, update, delete, and segment your contact list online.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-2x icon-radius float-left"></i>
            <p class="lead sub-text-blue float-right">Categorize your contacts accordingly so you can stay organize with your contact list.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="icon-box">
            <i class="fa fa-book fa-2x icon-radius float-left"></i>
            <p class="lead sub-text-blue float-right">Clean, manage, and grow your list. This app helps you stay organized year round.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="testimonials">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <h1 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center">Testimonials</h1><img class="img-thumbnail img-rounded mx-auto d-block" src="img/testimonial.jpg">
        <p class="lead sub-text-blue text-center">"I love contact hub. It has been helpful to me so far in managing my contacts.<br>
        I don't worry of loosing my contacts on my phone since I can easily jump on the app and take a<br>
        look on my contacts per category. Definitely recommended."</p>
        <h4 class="testimonials-name">- CHRISTINE JACOBS, Contact Hub User</h4>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p class="text-center">© Copyright 2020. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: how can I add a few pixels so that my fixed navbar wont cover up some parts of the div section?

Comment: like this 
 $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: topData.top + 20
  }, 'slow');